# Service for sharing list of installed apps

Tags: applications

I'm thinking of web app for sharing lists of installed / recommended apps with people.
Optional comment for each app on how/when/why it's useful. Something a bit similar to [usesthis.com](http://usesthis.com/), but for sharing Android apps and open to everyone. Is there such a service?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com).

Generically, a user's app list will be at `http://www.appbrain.com/user/{username}/apps-on-the-phone`.

You can also create other lists to share with the world.

Comment: Thanks, perfect! Here's my list by the way: http://www.appbrain.com/user/cuu508/cepes-apps

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not a webapp [ShareMyApps](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mattlary.shareMyApps&feature=order_history) is quite useful. It is tiny in size and can share application list via email where you can edit your application list freely.