# Share App list with friends?

Tags: applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Service for sharing list of installed apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12114/service-for-sharing-list-of-installed-apps)

Is there an app that would allow one to see my installed apps and if they like any to click on it and have it install on their computer?